# Magento 2 Commerce cloud : How to monitor/confirm that the results are served from elastic search?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2-cloud, magento-2-commerce

We are using elastic search in our store but I am not convinced that all the results are served from elastic search. Is there a tool/feature where we can monitor activity in elastic search server just like MONITOR on redis-cli, or access logs on apache?

We are using the Magento commerce cloud, but I would be open to tools not provided in commerce cloud stack as well to monitor things at least on dev machines.

**EDIT :**

I apologise if it wasn't clear from my examples but I want real time monitoring of requests served from elastic search to confirm that the search results are served from elastic search in my store.

Comment: That’s a good question. I have the same situation. Will try to check it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should using **magento-cloud ssh** and ssh to Magento Cloud Node such as **production**, **staging**

Using CURL to check Elasticsearch result [Elastic search document << here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html),

example: I want to get all product are belongs to Category **3**

```
  curl -X GET 'ip:port/[index]/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category_ids" : "3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000
}'
```

How can you get list of **[index]** please using

```
curl -x GET '[ip]:[port]/_cat/indices?v'
```

[image: Elasticsearch Indexes]

Absolutely you are also want to know product count, please using **"size": 1**

You can debug into **vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php:952** to dump query params are using on your project.

**Update 2:**

- You can using **Elasticsearch Tool Box** (Chrome Ext), connect to Cloud Server using **SSH Tunnel**.

Comment: How to monitor it on local?

Comment: Please using elasticsearch-toolbox (Chrome Ext), or using terminal as I mentioned.

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will confirm this after the weekend.

Comment: The tools you provided can track nodes,indices and run queries but it cannot be used to monitor requests to elasticsearch server as the question mentioned.

Comment: Just an FYI, if anyone needs a GUI for monitoring elasticsearch indices etc use "elasticvue"  chrome extension instead. It has a lot more features and a better ui.